# CodeIgniter RESTful API rate limiting issue

Tags: php, api, codeigniter

I am working with the following code written by Phil Sturgeon here: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver

No where in his docs can I see how the limit option is setup in side of the controller.

the RESTController controller file has some references e.g.

Line 654: https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver/blob/master/application/libraries/REST_Controller.php

Shows the protected function, additionally there is:

```
 // How many times can you get to this method an hour?
 $limit = $this->methods[$controller_method]['limit'];
```

And from the rest.php config:

> /*
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | REST Enable Limits
>   |-------------------------------------------------------------------------- | | When set to true REST_Controller will count the number of uses of
>   each method | by an API key each hour. This is a general rule that can
>   be overridden in the | $this->method array in each controller. |

Can anyone help me with this please? Pulling my hair out currently :-)

One of my controllers methods as it currently stands:

```
function listservices_get()
{
    $organisation_id = $this->get('id');
    $organisations = $this->api_buyus_model->list_services($organisation_id);

    if($organisations)
    {
            $this->response($organisations, 200);
    }
    else
    {
            $this->response(array('error' => '1', 'errorDesc' => 'Buy us services list could not be retrieved.'), 400);
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem?  Do you want no limit?  Do you want to set the limit to something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed with:

```
    protected $methods = array(
            'index_put' => array('level' => 10, 'limit' => 10),
            'index_delete' => array('level' => 10),
            'level_post' => array('level' => 10),
            'regenerate_post' => array('level' => 10),
    );
```

Comment: What's the 'level' index doing?

Comment: did you override this scope in the Controller?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like

`$this->methods['listservices_get']['limit'] =10` at the top of the function?

If you have a debugger, it might be worth setting a breakpoint in there to check what the limit is set to. and then you can override it before the reponse is called.

Comment: Managed to solve this (Answer below) hope others will find it helpful should they hit this issue too :-) Thanks for the reply though viperfx