# REST Controller bypasses the limit for each method

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

i have build a REST API in CodeIgniter using this: https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver

and trying to set limits for each method as mentioned here:

[CodeIgniter RESTful API rate limiting issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13252050/codeigniter-restful-api-rate-limiting-issue)

but it just does not work.

I have enabled limits in the rest.php file but still it just does not count the limit.

My code:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| REST Enable Limits
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| When set to TRUE, the REST API will count the number of uses of each method
| by an API key each hour. This is a general rule that can be overridden in the
| $this->method array in each controller
|
| Default table schema:
|   CREATE TABLE `limits` (
|       `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
|       `uri` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
|       `count` INT(10) NOT NULL,
|       `hour_started` INT(11) NOT NULL,
|       `api_key` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
|       PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
|   ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
|
| To specify the limits within the controller's __construct() method, add per-method
| limits with:
|
|       $this->method['METHOD_NAME']['limit'] = [NUM_REQUESTS_PER_HOUR];
|
| See application/controllers/api/example.php for examples
*/
$config['rest_enable_limits'] = TRUE;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| REST API Limits Table Name
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If not using the default table schema in 'rest_enable_limits', specify the
| table name to match e.g. my_limits
|
*/
$config['rest_limits_table'] = 'rest_api_limits';
```

and here is the methods array in my Controller:

```
     protected $methods = array(
        'properties_get' => array('level' => 20),
        'images_get' => array('level' => 20),
        'prices_get' => array('level' => 20),
        'availability_get' => array('level' => 20),
        'portals_get' => array('level' => 20, 'limit' => 10),
        'properties_post' => array('level' => 20, 'limit' => 10),
        'images_post' => array('level' => 20, 'limit' => 10),
        'availability_post' => array('level' => 20, 'limit' => 10),
        'prices_post' => array('level' => 20, 'limit' => 10),
        'enquiries_post' => array('level' => 20, 'limit' => 100),
        'properties_put' => array('level' => 20, 'limit' => 10),
        'enquiries_get' => array('level' => 20, 'limit' => 10),
        'bookings_get' => array('level' => 20, 'limit' => 10),
        'ferienhausmiete_get' => array('level' => 10, 'limit' => 20),
        'homeaway_get' => array('level' => 10, 'limit' => 600),
    );
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Show us the errors you are getting. If you aren't getting any errors then echo out from your methods to see if they are getting called.

Comment: that is the point. I am not getting any errors. My question is about limits. It does not count/update the limit, every time it adds a new row

Comment: did u solve this issue? i have the same problem